# How to reset MetaWear Device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently developing an application that will use Metawear device.
I have noticed that after I connect a device, I can read the live accelerometer values of that device but I want to read/download offline accelerometer values.

For that as per I refer https://gist.github.com/mbientlab/a299fc705f8ac3b64359 , I need to set Trigger.

But when I am setting triggers and if I did not remove that trigger then next time Metawear device unable to detect/scan by my device(Suppose an android mobile).

If device totally discharges and starts again then it resets.

So is there any method to remove that trigger without connecting to the device or reset the device

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the [removeAllTriggers](https://mbientlab.com/docs/metawear/android/1.8.0/com/mbientlab/metawear/api/controller/Logging.html#removeAllTriggers()) method to remove all logging triggers.  Line 100 of the [aforementioned gist](https://gist.github.com/mbientlab/a299fc705f8ac3b64359#file-loggingexample-java-L100) demonstrates trigger removal with the removeTrigger method